# HTML: why button does not show up inside a div but it does within a table?

Tags: html

Disclaimer: I'm not a web designer expert... my sense of beauty doesn't go beyond printf's formats.

Why this displays a button

```
<div id="redirMsg">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td><label id="redirMsgLabel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><button onclick="Redirect()">Redirect</button></td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

but this doesn't?

```
<div id="redirMsg">
    <label id="redirMsgLabel" />
    <button onclick="Redirect()">Redirect</button>
</div>
```

(Tried only in IE9...)

Thanks!

Comment: [Works in Chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/5LpX9/1/), Ubuntu 10.10...

Comment: Those labels are messed up, they won't work right.  First, INPUT elements of the "button" or "submit" type don't need a label.  Set a value attribute instead, e.g. `<input type="button" name="test" value="Test" />`.  Screen readers will read the value aloud.  For other types of inputs, use paired FOR/ID attributes.  Example: `<label for="user-name">User Name:</label> <input type="text" name="user_name" id="user-name" />`.  The FOR in the label corresponds to the ID of the associated INPUT.

Answer (score 1):

All else being equal, the botton will show up in both cases.

I'll hazard a guess that you have some CSS applied to the label that hides the content, and that you are not serving the document as application/xhtml+xml so the [label is missing its end tag](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-media-types/#C_3) and the button is inside it.

You shouldn't have a label anyway — a button keeps its label internally. If you do have one, then it should have a `for` attribute which matches the `id` attribute of the control to which it is associated.

Comment: Thanks David. Couple data points 1) there's no css being applied 2) will check the content type 3) the label is a holder for some text applied dynamically. Thanks, will go through your list and get back!